# Cannot retrieve correct parse image onto infoview

Tags: java, android, image, parse-platform

I am trying to get the correct image file from a parse table. I am able to get the image to show inside my infowindow , but its the wrong image. Is there a set up for this? Perhaps iterate through the parse items with some sort of id or TAG? Any guidance would be really appreciated. Here is the code I am using. (Issue inside inside the try catch block - picasso)

```
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.maps_infowindow, null);
                v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (mapFragment.getView().getMeasuredWidth() * .9), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(marker.getTitle());
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc)).setText(marker.getSnippet());
                ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);


                //icon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.back_vision_fade);
                ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Places");
                if(searchType!=null && searchType.length()>0) {
                    ArrayList<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(String type: searchType.split("\\|")) types.add(type);
                    query.whereContainedIn("icon", types);
                }
                try {
                    List<ParseObject> objects = query.find();
                    for(ParseObject obj : objects){
                        if(obj.getParseFile("icon")!=null) {

                            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(obj.getParseFile("icon").getUrl()).into(icon, new MarkerCallback(marker));
                            //item.downloadIcon(getActivity());
                        }
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                }
                return v;
            }
        }

    );
```